# Не отправить большую строку POSTом

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, iis

Здравствуйте! Через ajax пытаюсь отправить строку (файлы закодированные в base64) типа json. Проблема в том, что если кодирую файлы общим объемом примерно до 10мб, то отрабатывает успешно. Если объем увеличить к примеру до 15мб, то выдает ошибку "500 Internal Server Error". В PHP *post_max_size=100M*, сервер на IIS, там *maxAllowedContentLength* тоже 100мб. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: В конфиге PHP есть еще upload_max_filesize. Может, в этом дело. Или в конфиге сервера. У Апача есть LimitRequestBody, за IIS не скажу. А может PHP просто памяти не хватает на дальнейшие действия с этими файлами. Опять же за IIS не скажу, но под LAMP при нехватке памяти PHP вылетает именно со статусом 500.

Comment: дак большую строку или файл?

Comment: @alexander-zonov, upload_max_filesize не влияет на это, так как учитывается только при передаче файлов, а в моем случае - строка. Можно ли как-то решить проблему нехватки памяти?

Comment: @teran, содержимое файла кодируется в base64 и получается большая строка

Comment: в логах то пусто?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error - это не ошибка как таковая - php скрипт может и отработает, только вот браузер уже ждать его не будет - сам сталкивался неоднократно. Можно в сервак и не лазить а написать в принимающем скрипте ini_set('max_execution_time', '3600'); Если этого не хватит - то все упирается в браузер

Comment: @Mcile 500-я ошибка это как раз ошибка в скрипте. А то о чем вы говорите это 504-я.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо! Проблема решилась. В php.ini увеличил значение параметра *memory_limit*, он обозначает максимальное количество оперативной памяти, которое может быть выделено скрипту